# How do I prevent the bottom of the section above from leaking into the top of the next one (fullPage.js)

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I've had this issue many times, where the scroll is off from the sections and it creates an effect where the top of a section is actually the bottom of one previous. I have an image in a section with `position: absolute` on it, is that the problem?

[Link](http://users.lk.net/~vityav/schoolsites/tungsenpr.html)

Edit: Code

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORjzPo)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/jquery.fullPage.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                verticalCentered: false,
                css3: false
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #intro {
            backgroundSize: 100% 10% !important;
            color: white;
        }
        img {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section" id="intro">
            <img src="https://aos.iacpublishinglabs.com/question/aq/1400px-788px/many-lumens-100-watt-incandescent-light-bulb-give-off_2c6301bc5ccd144.jpg?domain=cx.aos.ask.com"></img>
            <h1>Tungsten: It'l light up your day!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="gallery">
            <div class="slide">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">asdfasdf
            </div>
            <div class="slide">asdfasdfasdf
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like so... but without any code or reproduction nobody is going to be able to tell you with any accuracy at all.

Comment: @Alvaro Link Added

Comment: I don't know what's happening there... But that <h1> tag is somehow responsible for that issue... However, I'm guessing that something else should be the real trouble-maker... Can you copy and paste your html code here? Because fullpage.js is doing some modifications to the website and is hard to know what's the original code...

Comment: Apparently, adding a container inside (each) .section, with position:absolute, and inside this container all the "section code" (i.e: the img and the h1) will do the trick

Comment: Thanks! I had this issue before and solved it somehow, too.